# Javascript mousewheel event scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following http://jsfiddle.net/o0krp0yf/ basically if I scroll with mouse wheel, stop it (I want to scroll slides). But my problem is if I have an element with normal scroll behavior I have no way of scrolling that element (see `.scroll`).

Is there anyway to detect if an element (which the cursor is over, ie I want to scroll that element) is scrollable or has scrollbars, and if it does I want to scroll that element normally.

Basically I want to allow my normal method to work perfectly, unless I am trying to scroll `.scroll` element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set a flag when you `mouseover` the element. Something like this:

```
var disableScroll = true;

$(document).on('mouseenter mouseleave', '.scroll', function(e) {
    disableScroll = (e.type == 'mouseleave');
});
```

And then check against the flag in your scroll event:

```
$('.page').on('mousewheel', function(event) {
    if (disableScroll) {
        event.preventDefault();    
    }
});
```

Here's an updated fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/o0krp0yf/1/

You might want to add a check to see if the inner scrolling element has completed scrolling (otherwise, the scroll event will continue to the parent, which isn't desired...)

Answer (score 0):

just remove the `event.preventDefault();` from your script. By default any element with the scroll bar will be scrolled naturally. Do you want to do something else when an element with scroll bar, apart from scroll?

Comment: I can't remove it I need it. Read the original post.